# Unable to upload a file inside my Content folder, after publishing my asp.net mvc web application to IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the following action method , which add an uploaded file to a folder:-

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string ADusername = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    repository.InsertOrUpdateDataCenter(dc, ADusername);
                    repository.Save();
                    if (DataCenterfile != null)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(DataCenterfile.FileName);

                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/uploads")), dc.ID + ".png");
                        DataCenterfile.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = dc.ID });
                }
```

but i am getting the following exception:-

```
Server Error in '/TMS' Application.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TMS\Content\uploads\97.png'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TMS\Content\uploads\97.png'.

Source Error:
```

baring in mind that the above was working well , but after i have published my web application to the IIS i start receiving this error. so can anyone advice how i can solve this  ?
Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but does the `/Content` folder exist in the IIS site where it was published to? It could be possible that it was not included when publishing.

Comment: thanks, i checked the IIS manager and u are right the upload folder is not inside the IIS , altohugh it is part of my applicatino when accessing the application on visual studio . can u adivce why it was not included and how i can included it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The upload folder is not inside the IIS , so i have to manually Publish it.

Comment: could you please describe your answer?

Answer (score 3):

I *believe* what you want to do is to set the "Build Action" for the `Content` folder as "Content".

You can do this by selecting the folder in the Solution Explorer, then go under Properties. There you will see the "Build Action" option. Set that to "Content", or maybe "None".

Comment: there is no option under the Properties to set the Build action, So what i did is that i right click on the folder then i select to Publish this folder. and it was published to IIS , but still i am note sure why this folder was not included in my first Publish, and should i publish this folder manually ?